# Algorithm to distribute bits evenly but with increasing density

Tags: algorithm, distribution, frequency

I'm looking for an algorithm to generate a series of bits such that the density at the start of the series is very low (i.e. mostly 0s), and by the end of the series is very high (i.e. mostly 1s). I've got this to work by varying the probability that a random number would fall within a range, but I'd like to find a more structured [read: deterministic] algorithm, like some sort of way to steadily increase the density of 1s.

Does anyone know of something similar? Or perhaps some reading on such topics? It's proving to be quite fun to think about but also rather challenging (unless I'm missing something simple)!

Comment: More structued = deterministic?

Comment: Yes sorry, that's what I meant. Thanks @maraca

Comment: So what does "deterministic" get you that pseudorandom numbers won't?

Comment: My only problem with pseudorandom numbers is that they have the possibility of creating zones of unexpected density (for example, a group of several ones in a row in a region where there should be mostly zeros), and I'm looking for the smoothest possible distribution. Otherwise they'd be my first pick!

Comment: @janizer That's the nature of "density" as found in the real world.  There are always localized clusters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A very general way to do this deterministically (no random numbers) is with a sigma-delta modulator.

Pick a smoothly increasing function that starts at 0 and ends at 1. Then use the modulator algorithm to approximate with 0's and 1's.

NB: Sigma-delta modulators are very commonly used in electronics to convert analog signals (sound, video, etc.) to 1/0 bit streams.

For illustration, I'll take a ramp from 0 to 1 over a period of 100 and use a first-order converter.  But you could choose any curve you like. For example, a [hyperbolic tangent](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HyperbolicTangent.html) scaled horizontally will give smaller start and finish slope with more rapid change in the middle. And a second order converter might provide "nicer" patterns. They tend to be a bit less regular.

It's a very simple algorithm. In C:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  int x_max = 99;
  double vn = 0;
  for (int x = 0; x <= x_max; ++x) {
    double xn = (double) x / x_max; // linear ramp from 0 to 1.
    int yn = vn > 0.5;
    printf("%d", yn);
    vn += xn - yn;
  }
  printf("\n");
  return 0;
}
```

As you can see, it's deterministic. It's also very simple and fast: no trig functions, exponentials, etc. That's why it's good for hardware implementation.

Output split into 2 lines for easier viewing:

```
00000000000100000010000100010001001001001010100101
01010110101011011011011101110111101111110111111111
```

[Here](http://repository.upenn.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1144&context=ese_papers) is a seminal paper on sigma-delta conversion. The variables in the program above match Figure 8.  Figure 13 shows a second-order diagram if you want to try that.

For fun, here's a run with an interval of 1000:

```
00000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000
00000010000000000000001000000000000100000000001000
00000010000000010000000100000001000000010000001000
00010000010000010000010000010000010000100001000010
00010000100001000010001000010001000100001000100010
00100010001000100100010001001000100100010010001001
00010010010010010001001001001001001001001001001001
00101001001001001010010010100100101001010010010100
10100101010010100101001010100101010010101010010101
01001010101010100101010101010101010010101010101010
10101010101010101101010101010101010110101010101011
01010101101010101101010110101011010110101101010110
10110101101101011010110110101101101011011011011010
11011011011011011011011011011011011101101101101101
11011011101101110110111011011101110110111011101110
11101110111011110111011101111011101111011110111101
11101111011110111101111101111101111101111101111101
11111011111101111111011111110111111101111111101111
11111011111111110111111111111011111111111111101111
11111111111111111101111111111111111111111111111111
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, evenly spread distribution and adaptable. Plus extra reading in that paper! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

One approach which is quite flexible is to use a [logistic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function) for the probability of generating 1 vs 0. This presumes you know the length of the sequence *a priori*, but gives you lots of flexibility for the rate of ramp-up, and the minimum and maximum probability of getting a 1.

Since you didn't specify a language, I prototyped this in Ruby:

```
# Creates an array of desired length whose values are symmetric
# about the mid-point of the array, are bounded below and above
# by min & max, and have a ramp up rate determined by steepness.
def logistic_function(length, min, max, steepness)
  mid = 0.5 * (length - 1)
  range = max - min
  # create, initialize elements via logistic fn, and return resulting array
  Array.new(length) { |x| min + range / (1 + Math.exp(-steepness * (x - mid))) }
end

length = 80
# 80 probabilities will vary from 0.1 to 0.9, with a relatively slow ramp-up
probability = logistic_function(length, 0.1, 0.9, 0.1)

# Create an array of bits where each entry's probability of being 1
# is determined by the logistic function we generated
bits = Array.new(length) { |i| rand <= probability[i] ? 1 : 0 }
puts bits.join
```

Sample output from running twice:

```
00000000011000001000001100001101001010000011001011001111000111011111101011111011
10100000000000000000010000010111000000110110111011111000111011111111111110111111
```

The results are random, but you can (stochastically) control the density of 1's and the rate of transition via `min`, `max`, and `steepness`.

Note that by the symmetry of the logistic function, the overall proportion of 1 bits has expected value `(min + max) / 2`.  With the parameterization I used in my example, that's 0.5.  To illustrate this I counted the number of 1's in a set of 80 bits, and repeated generating/counting for 10,000 trials.  Since the expected proportion is 0.5, the expected number of 1's on each trial is 40. Here are the empirical results:

[image: Beautiful bell-shaped curve with sample mean 39.99, 95% confidence interval from 39.92 to 40.07]

Answer (score 0):

There a several possibilities to do this, it depends on the distribution you want to have. Here is a very simple example that I think should work for your purpose:

```
for (i=0; i<end; i++)
  value = rand(0,1) * (2*i/end) * (2*(end-i)/end);
  if(i>end/2)
    value = 1 - value;
```

Where rand(0,1) generates a value between 0 and 1. At the end you have to round the result.

Edit: I did a quick implementation of the algorithm and simulated it 50 times (with end = 500). It shows the distribution of ones and zeros (before rounding). [image]

Answer (score 0):

If the 0s and 1s are set perfectly then you can divide the result in the middle and the left half should have 1/3 of 1s compared to the right half (in other words: the left half has 1/4 of all the ones and the right half has 3/4 of the ones). So we could use this idea to generate the bits.

```
private static boolean[] res;

public static boolean[] generate(int len) {
    res = new boolean[len];
    generate(0, len, len / 2);
    return res;
}

private static void generate(int start, int len, int bits) {
    if (bits == len)
        for (int i = start; i < start + len; i++)
            res[i] = true;
    else if (bits > 0) {
        int l1 = len / 2, l2 = len - l1, b1 = (bits + 2) / 4, b2 = bits - b1;
        if (l2 < b2) {
            b2 = l2;
            b1 = bits - b2;
        }
        generate(start, l1, b1);
        generate(start + l1, l2, b2);
    }
}
```

Output for 63, 64 and 65 bits:

```
000000100000001000100010001011100010001000111111111111111111111
0000000100000001000100010001011100010001010111111111111111111111
00000001000000010001000100010111000100010001111111111111111111111
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Gaussian Distribution which is highly used in many application.

I used Matlab as it is easy for this kind of application but it should be easy to convert to another language.

So, let say you want to create an array of 20 values with the criteria you asked.

```
len = 20;
x = 1:len; 
y = normdist(x, len, len/5);  % you can play with mean and standard deviation.
plot(x,y)
```

[image: Gaussian Dist]

Then, add randomness to the equation and add a threshold as you wish.

```
rn = rand(1,len);
res = y.*rn;
```

[image: After random]

And add a threshold, let say the ones below the mean are zero.

[image: stem]

You can play with the values and get a set of values as you need.